# MemSQL - Replicating and Partitioning a Table dynamically

Tags: sql, in-memory-database, singlestore

I'm very new to MemSQL and primarily have a RDBMS background. I'm running MemSQL with high_availability set to false, and would like to see performance based on different partitioning and replication schemes.

However, in trying to dynamically replicate and partition, I cannot find any documentation - as most replication documentations are about replicating to entire clusters (and not nodes), and most partitioning documents indicate to setting partitions during schema definition.

Could someone please advise on how it would be possible to do something like this, which can be done in PostgreSQL:

### Replication of a table

```sql
ALTER TABLE table DISTRIBUTE BY REPLICATION
```

### Partitioning of a table

```sql
ALTER TABLE table DISTRIBUTE BY HASH(attribute)
```

Answer (score 1):

Replication in MemSQL is based on physical storage, i.e. each primary partition replicates directly to the corresponding secondary partition, so that it can be highly performant. This means the partitioning cannot be changed via replication. To try out different partitioning schemes, you would need to copy the data into another version of the table with the schema changed as desired. One way you can do that is to create the new version of the table and use INSERT INTO ... SELECT FROM to copy the data.